# Apache Spark - Connection refused for worker

Tags: akka, apache-spark

Hi I was new to apache spark and i was trying to learn it

While creating a new standalone cluster I met with this error.

I started my master and it is active in port 7077, i can see that in the ui (port 8080)

While startting the server using the command

```
 ./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://192.168.0.56:7077
```

I am meeting with a connection refused error

```
14/07/22 13:18:30 ERROR EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkWorker@node-        physical:55124] -> [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.0.56:7077]: Error [Association failed     with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.0.56:7077]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.0.56:7077]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2:     Connection refused: /192.168.0.56:7077
```

Please help me with the error i am sruck here for a long time.

I hope the information is enough. Please help

Comment: can you do `telnet 192.168.0.56  7077`  from a worker node and get a connection?

Comment: no i cant do that

Trying 192.168.0.56...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: Then it's a network issue. How is your network topology? Is the Master and the workers on the same network?  Can they resolve each other by hostname, ipaddress or both?

Comment: yeah they are connected by the same lan network ...

Comment: What's the ip of the worker node? You should be able to telnet to the master from a worker and get a connection. Check your settings.

Comment: ip of the worker node in 192.168.0.26..

i tried from worker node only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57745/discussion-between-maasg-and-user2728024).

Comment: i removed all ips which are not used in the cluster it worked after that :)

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I went to /etc/hosts and :

- removed the line with 127.0.1.1 and it worked.
- wrote "MASTER_IP MACHINE_NAME"

Comment: Merely commenting out the 127.0.1.1 line worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Removed the line with `127.0.1.1`, then the hostname is resolved to the first available IP address of the network interface card. Thus, the spark service can be accessed by workers.

Comment: @GaryWang you mean the line `127.0.1.1 localhost`?

Answer (score 6):

Try "./sbin/start-master -h ". It works, when I specify the host name as IP address.

Comment: Works in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Change the **SPARK_MASTER_HOST=< ip>** in the **spark-env.sh** of the master node.

Then restart the master, if you grep the process you will see it changes from

java -cp /spark/conf/:/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host **< HOST NAME>** --port 7077 --webui-port 8080

to

java -cp /spark/conf/:/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host **< HOST IP>** --port 7077 --webui-port 8080

Answer (score 1):

Check if your firewall is turned off as it might be blocking the worker connection by either turning off the firewall temporarily:

```
$ sudo service iptables stop
```

or permanently:

```
$ sudo chkconfig iptables off
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems like spark is very picky about IP and machine names. so, when starting your master, it will use your machine name to register spark master. if that name is not reachable from your workers, it will be almost impossible to reach.

a way to solve it, is to start your master like this:

```
SPARK_MASTER_IP=YOUR_SPARK_MASTER_IP ${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-master.sh
```

then, you will be able to connect your slaves like this

`${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://YOUR_SPARK_MASTER_IP:PORT`

i hope it helps!

Comment: There seems no `SPARK_MASTER_IP`, but `SPARK_MASTER_HOST` as the answer [Hohenheimsenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594145/6571140) mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem in a docker container, I solved it by setting the IP for master and driver as localhost, specifically:

```
    set('spark.master.hostname' ,'localhost')
    set('spark.driver.hostname', 'localhost')
```

Answer (score 0):

did you add the entries of master and worker nodes in etc/hosts, if not add every machines ip and host name mappings in all the machines.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows: spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master -h [Interface IP to bind to]

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a DNS and I added entries in `/etc/hosts` in the master node to refer to the IPs and hostnames of all master and worker nodes. In worker nodes, I added the IP and hostname of the master node in `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ifconfig** command to know your private IP.
Then, use that IP on your **start-master.sh** script like this:

```
./start-master.sh --host 192.168.1.15 --port 7077
```

At this point, use **telnet** command like this:

```
telnet 192.168.1.15 7077
```

and the ouput should confirm that you were able to connect without any issue:

```
Trying 192.168.1.15...
Connected to 192.168.1.15.
```

Finally, use **start-worker.sh** script like this:

```
start-worker.sh spark://192.168.1.15:7077
```